# PHP Echo does not return Table data with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am working on a leaderboard. The leaderboard gets data from my SQL Database. It is using the old method of MySQL because I'm not familiar with MySQLi yet.

I don't want to add a row everytime, so I'm using a php method to repeat it. But I got a issue with it. It is returning nothing what I've put in the echo.

This is my complete code:
https://gist.github.com/matthijs110/accb1b0b69570c4d3f50

It looks fine to me, and I can't find any errors. The result of the current code looks like this:

http://puu.sh/8HP64.png

About the warning: I don't know why and how it came there, It says the problem is this line:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
```

I've used that if check multiple times on other pages without any issues.

What is wrong?

Comment: It seems you don't have a working query. Perhaps `TABLE_NAME` should be a variable instead of a constant?

Comment: I would suggest you try it without the funk around the table name: `SELECT Username, Wins FROM theTableName ORDER BY Wins DESC` and see how you go.

Comment: @Fluffeh Edited the post, forgot to add the Database connection code.
And I've done that multiple times :/

Comment: The warning you are seeing mostly means that you have a syntax error in your MySQL query. Are you sure that these col names are capitalized? Use `echo mysql_error($db);`to see the error. BTW Stop using `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated and insecure. Use `mysqli_*` instead.

Comment: @wumm I'm going to use MySQLi a.s.a.p. And yes, they are capitalized. This the result when echoing the error:
http://puu.sh/8HPJM.png

Comment: Would you mind just copying and pasting the error message into your posts/ comment, it's much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to make a query using the **mysql_ library** but you haven't opened a connection with it. You've opened a connection with the **mysqli_ library**.

Pick either `mysqli_` or `mysql_` (or PDO) and stick to it. Don't switch database libraries mid-script. *(Don't pick mysql_, it is deprecated).*

In your connection page you are using `mysqli_` library

```
if($mysqli->connect_errno) {
```

But in you complete code you are trying to get data using `mysql` library

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
```

**Mysqli PHP:**

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","peter","abc123","my_db");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Username,Wins FROM Leaderboard_Tag ORDER BY Wins DESC");
$rank = 1;
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) >= 1) {
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$Username=$row['Username'];
$Wins=$row['Wins'];
                                echo "<td>$rank</td>
                                    <td>Ava</td>
                                    <td>$Username</td>
                                    <td>$Wins</td>";
                        $rank++;
                            }
 }
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: So what do I need to change to use the complete MySQLi Libary?

Comment: @user3625127  use this instead mysqli_num_rows($result)

Answer (score 0):

your only problem here it maybe you forgot to include your connection file.

```
   include("your connection file here");
```

EDIT:

you are mixing between mysql and mysqli .

change this

```
    if (mysql_num_rows($result)) {
```

to

```
    if ($result->num_rows > 0)) {
```

EDIT:

you need to change the mysql fetch also to mysqli.

change this

```
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
```

to

```
     $result->execute(); // Execute the prepared query.
    $result->store_result();
    $result->bind_result($Username, $Wins); 
    while($row = $result->fetch()){
            echo $Username;
            echo $Wins;
    }
```

Comment: I don't have a connection file. I put it at the top of the page.

Complete code: https://gist.github.com/matthijs110/accb1b0b69570c4d3f50

Comment: Okay, I've used that, no more errors, but it still doesn't return anything from the echo.
http://puu.sh/8HQmo.png

Answer (score 0):

***important**

from php 5.5.0 mysql function is deprecated(soft)

> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include: mysqli_connect()
>   PDO::__construct()

Therefore it is better not to use Mysql in general, try to learn PDO.